# Not Found Page Working On Backend But Not Working at Frontend Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, http-status-code-404

I have yii installed on my live server we have two interfaces one backend and one frontend. In backend we add products and in front end the view is rendered for the products. The problem is that for example this is our website https://mmstore.be/products/714/IPhone-12-Mini-Scherm-Reparatie product page if you put anything at the last of the url like this https://mmstore.be/products/714/IPhone-12-Mini-Scherm-Reparatie/03003300303094949949494 the page will remain the same means it should be showing not found page but the same page comes again.

Below is my config file code frontend.

```
<?php
$params = array_merge(
require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params.php',
require __DIR__ . '/../../common/config/params-local.php',
require __DIR__ . '/params.php',
require __DIR__ . '/params-local.php'
);

 return [
'id' => 'app-frontend',
'basePath' => dirname(__DIR__),
'bootstrap' => ['log'],
'controllerNamespace' => 'frontend\controllers',
'components' => [
    'request' => [
        'csrfParam' => '_csrf-frontend',
    ],
'cache' => [
        'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',],
    'user' => [
        'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
        'enableAutoLogin' => true,
        'identityCookie' => ['name' => '_identity-frontend', 'httpOnly' => true],
    ],
    'session' => [
        // this is the name of the session cookie used for login on the frontend
        'name' => 'advanced-frontend',
    ],
    'log' => [
        'traceLevel' => YII_DEBUG ? 3 : 0,
        'targets' => [
            [
                'class' => 'yii\log\FileTarget',
                'levels' => ['error', 'warning'],
            ],
        ],
    ],
   'errorHandler' => [
        'errorAction' => 'site/error',
    ],
   


  'urlManager' => [


  'baseUrl' => '',
  'enablePrettyUrl' => false,
  'showScriptName' => false,
  'enableStrictParsing' => true,
  'rules'=>array(
  '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
            'class' => 'yii\web\UrlNormalizer',
  'collapseSlashes' => true,
  'normalizeTrailingSlash' => true,
  ),

  ],
  ],
'params' => $params,
 ];
```

i have error.php in my site directory and below is its code

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $name string */
/* @var $message string */
/* @var $exception Exception */

use yii\helpers\Html;

$this->title = $name;
?>
```

```
<h1><?= Html::encode($this->title) ?></h1>

<div class="alert alert-danger">
    <?= nl2br(Html::encode($message)) ?>
</div>

<p>
    The above error occurred while the Web server was processing your request.
</p>
<p>
    Please contact us if you think this is a server error. Thank you.
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is strange that you  disabled "enablePrettyUrl", and using pretty url. If "/products/" is a controller name and assuming "IPhone-12-Mini-Scherm-Reparatie" is a parameter named "url" then you can change urlManager like this:

```
'urlManager' => [
        'enablePrettyUrl' => true,
        'showScriptName' => false,
        'rules' => [
            '/'=>'site/index',
            '/products/<id>/<url>'=>'products/view',
            '/products/<id>'=>'products/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        ],
    ],
```

in controller it should be something like this

```
public function actionView($id, $url) {
    $product = Product::find()->where(['id'=>$id])->one();
    // ...
}
```